# Orthogonal complement of $H_a =\left\{g \in V: g\left(t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=g(t) \right\}$

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

If $\;\;V=\{ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C} |\; f \text{ is continuous and has period }1\}$, $\;\; \langle f | g \rangle$ is defined as $ \displaystyle \langle f | g \rangle = \int_0^1 \overline{f(t)}g(t)dt$, $\forall f,g \in V\;\;$ and $\displaystyle \;\;H_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} =\left\{g\in V: g\left(t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=g(t) \right\}$.

($f \text{ has period } 1$)

($g \text{ has period } 1 \text{ and } \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$)

---

What can be said about $H_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^\perp$?

### $H_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^\perp = \{f\in V: \langle f | g \rangle=0, \forall g\in H_a \}
= \left\{f\in V: \langle f | g \rangle=0, \forall g: g\left(t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=g(t) \right\}$

$\displaystyle 0 = \langle f | g \rangle = \int_0^1 \overline{f(t)}g(t)dt
= \int_0^1 \overline{f(t)}g\left(t+n+\frac{m}{\sqrt{2}}\right)dt, \;\; n,m \in \mathbb{Z}, \;\; f\in H_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^\perp, \;\; g\in H_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}$.

---

Related post: [Orthogonal complement of $H_a =\left\{g \in V: g\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)=g(t) \right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006189/orthogonal-complement-of-h-a-left-g-in-v-g-leftt-frac12-right-gt)

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}\frac1{\sqrt2}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user10354138  What does it mean for a set to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$?